#  How can I group by a list of elements?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, group-by

I run into this issue again and again: how can I group a list of objects by a containing list of other objects?

I have a list of objects of type `A` and each of these objects has an property (lets call it `ListProp`) which is a list also. `ListProp` has elements of the type `B`. There are multiple elements of type `A` with identically `B`-objects in `ListProp`, but the `ListProp` property reference differs from element to element. How can I group these `A`-objects the fastest way, where the `B`-objects in `ListProp` are identically?

Sample code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var exampleList = new List<A>
        {
            // Should be in first group
            new A { ListProp = new List<B>
            {
                new B { Prop = new C { Number = 0 }},
                new B { Prop = new C { Number = 1 }}
            }},
            // Should be in first group
            new A { ListProp = new List<B>
            {
                new B { Prop = new C { Number = 0 }},
                new B { Prop = new C { Number = 1 }}
            }},
            // Should be in second group
            new A { ListProp = new List<B>
            {
                new B { Prop = new C { Number = 0 }},
                new B { Prop = new C { Number = 1 }},
                new B { Prop = new C { Number = 1 }}
            }},
            // Should be in third group
            new A { ListProp = new List<B>
            {
                new B { Prop = new C { Number = 0 }},
                new B { Prop = new C { Number = 0 }}
            }}
        };

        // Doesn't work because the reference of ListProp is always different
        var groupedExampleList = exampleList.GroupBy(x => x.ListProp);
    }
}

class C
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public override bool Equals(object o)
    {
        if (o is C)
            return Number.Equals(((C)o).Number);
        else
            return false;
    }
}

class B
{
    public C Prop { get; set; }
}

class A
{
    public IList<B> ListProp { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why the last should be in third group? It should be in first, shouldn't i?

Comment: Because the number of elements should be the same as well. 0,1 != 0,1,1

Comment: Ok that was improper edit. Clear now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can implement `IEqualityComparer<List<B>>` and use it in the other GroupBy overload.

```
public class ListOfBEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<List<B>>
{
    public bool Equals(List<B> x, List<B> y)
    {
        // you can also implement IEqualityComparer<B> and use the overload
        return x.SequenceEqual(y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(List<B> obj)
    {
        //implementation of List<T> may not work for your situation
        return obj.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Then you can use the overload

```
var groupedExampleList = exampleList.GroupBy(x => x.ListProp, 
                                             new ListOfBEqualityComparer());
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot :) Why am I always forgetting these to things: SequenceEquals and using a custom comparer. You saved my day and especially my weekend ;)

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
GroupBy(x => String.Join(",", x.ListProp));
```

It will group by `0,1; 0,1; 0,1; 0,1,1; 0,1` accordingly.

Comment: thanks for your thought, but this only works for the example. My objects are much more complex, so it would be hard to do it in this way. But for a simple approach this is a good idea.

Comment: @germanSharper: You know this sounds like a calculating a hash-code from an object (aim the same is your: equal by a criteria objects should return an equal value/hash-code). It could be a list or class. In our framework the common approach is to delimit the meaningful properties: "A:B:C:D:".

Comment: @germanSharper: Also you can compare both of the solutions: delimit/join items inside custom comparer. Makes sense to me

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this the following way:

1. Associate each child element (in ListProp property) with its parent
2. Group the parents by children
3. Project the results

---

```
var data = exampleList.SelectMany(a=>a.ListProp.Select(x=>new{Key = x.Prop.Number, Value = a}))
           .GroupBy(x=>x.Key)
           .Select(g=>new {Number = g.Key, Items = g.ToList()});
```